# Why firebase upload tasksnapshot is return only 0 and 100% progress?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase upload manager return only 0 to 100 % while uploading file.
Many users of stackoverflow said,

- it happens only when file size<256 kb(very small size)
- it is working better only when file size is larger approx 2 to 3 MB.

But i want smooth 0,1,2,3,...100% of uploading task, is it possible ,if yes please explain.

```
filepath.putFile(sendingImageURI).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                                {
                                    double progress = ((100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount())/100;
                                    Progressbar.setProgress((int) progress);
                                    progressText.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                                    Log.i("progress",String.valueOf(progress));//this print 0 and 100 only
                                }
                            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you already have your answer: "it happens only when file size<256 kb(very small size)".  The SDK is only going to invoke your callback for larger increments of uploaded bytes.  There is no way to control this programmatically, unless you build your own version of the SDK using [code from GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-storage) that works the way you want.  You can always [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) if you would like different behavior.

Comment: so its not possible (not IMPOSSIBLE) till now and only possible by build our own SDK. Thanx